# Correct way to setup a custom cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Man, it's annoying how I have to keep referring back to my old xcode projects to find out how to setup a custom cell in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method only because of the magnitude of methods I've seen.

What is the correct code for setting up a custom cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method without the use of storyboards?

I am currently doing something like this:

```
//This works for me btw
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"customcell";
CustomTableViewCell *customCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (customCell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    customCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Then I see other people using `loadWithNibName` and others that are registering their nibs in the viewDidLoad method using the `registerWithNib` method.

What in the world is the correct way to setup a custom cell in the delegate method?

I have also been told recently that I dont need to call the `dequeueReusable..` method when I'm dealing with custom cells. Can someone please clarify the correct way to setup your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method once and for all for me. Without the use of story boards. I have correctly setup my custom cell view with its respective `.m` and `.h` files.

Answer (score 1):

If it is CustomTableViewCell nib file exist in same UITableViewController nib your code will works fine. Otherwise you need to load nib file in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(cell==nil){
NSArray * nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:NULL];

NSEnumerator * nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
NSObject * nibItem = nil;

while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {

    if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        cell=(CustomTableViewCell*)nibItem;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Yeah, this feels hackish.